# PHP Startup: Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: php, timezone, runkit

I have juste updated my CentOS server. PHP is now at the 5.2.10 version (php-5.2.10-1.el5.remi.i386), and I have installed PECL Runkit. tzdata was updated too (tzdata-2009i-2.el5.noarch). Since the update, Apache refuse to start

Here is the httpd/error.log

[Wed Jul 08 11:40:21 2009] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jul 08 11:40:24 2009] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jul 08 11:40:24 2009] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Strict Standards:  PHP Startup: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/Berlin' for 'CEST/2.0/DST' instead in Unknown on line 0

**PHP Fatal error:  PHP Startup: Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in Unknown on line 0**

When I remove runkit, all run fine. But I need this tools.

Best regards, Cédric

Answer (score 0):

I install runkit without using yum, and it's fine

```
cvs -d :pserver:cvsread@cvs.php.net:/repository checkout pecl/runkit
2ième étape: compiler et installer:
cd pecl/runkit
pecl build package.xml
./configure
make
make install
```

add a /etc/php.d/runkit.ini

```
extension=runkit.so
```

add this in php.ini

```
[runkit]
runkit.internal_override = On
```