# Runkit : does not work on a linux server

Tags: php, runkit

I have a problem with PECL::Runkit with this little example

```
index.php contain <?php
runkit_import('a.php');
runkit_import('b.php');
Doublon::get();
```

a.php et b.php each contain the same code

```
class Doublon
{
static function get() { echo "class " . __FILE__; }
}
```

On my PC (Windows XP, Wampserver 2, php 5.2.9-2, runkit DLL bundled with
Wamp) it work and index.php show

```
class C:\wamp2\www\utilitaires\essais\runkit\b.php
```

On my Linux CentOS 5 server, PHP 5.2.10, Runkit compiled by hand

```
Warning: runkit_import() [function.runkit-import]: class doublon not
found in /shares/public/cedric/test/index.php on line 2
Warning: runkit_import() [function.runkit-import]: Cannot redeclare
class doublon in /shares/public/cedric/test/index.php on line 2
Warning: runkit_import() [function.runkit-import]: class doublon not
found in /shares/public/cedric/test/index.php on line 3
Warning: runkit_import() [function.runkit-import]: Cannot redeclare
class doublon in /shares/public/cedric/test/index.php on line 3
Fatal error: Class 'Doublon' not found in
/shares/public/cedric/test/index.php on line 4
```

One problem : runkit's make test give me 100% of tests failed, but I still don't know why.
The runkit version from the linux distribution just make crash Apache : 
[PHP Startup: Timezone database is corrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097105/php-startup-timezone-database-is-corrupt)

I dropped xdebug, return to php 5.2.9, but the errors are the same

Thanks in advance, Cédric

Answer (score 1):

[The Package site](http://pecl.php.net/package/runkit) says:

```
WARNING: 0.9 does not compile with PHP 5.2+ so use the CVS version instead.
```

Are you using the CVS version?

Comment: Are you using rpm's on windows? Also, I don't know why your version doesn't work, but you will most definitely need to compile yourself.

Comment: Non, RPM on Centos (fork of Redhat). I had compiled CVS version but it does not work.

Comment: hm weird.. I don't know in that case.. I would attempt to compile it yourself. It's really simple! Assuming you have PEAR installed, just hit:

pecl install Runkit-beta

Comment: But I had compiled Runkit by myself already, and it is the compiled version which don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The up-to-date runkit extension can be found on http://github.com/zenovich/runkit

Anyway, as I know, runkit never had a feature to define new class on importing. It only can add or change members of existing classes. If you really want this, you can open the feature-request on http://github.com/zenovich/runkit

To determine why you get different results on your platforms, I need to know the versions of runkit and PHP for both of them. You can get all the information using the command 'php -i'.